# Best practive for finding unit-tests? (if not developing test-first)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testing-strategies

At some point you have to decide which parts of your programm you want to cover with unit-tests.

If you're developing test-first then you're off the hook as you already have your test cases. Congratulations. If you're not so lucky (that's the case in our project) you have to decide for which parts of your programm you are going to write unit-tests.

**Is there a good and methodic approach to decide what to cover with unitt-tests**? Ecspecially one that is more specific than asking yourself `what should I test here?`?

Comment: You got it all turned upside down. Unit tests are to test the smallest bits worth testing, individually. And testing for all execution paths/different behaviors/important corner cases.

Comment: I didn't mean one unit test for all that. Definitely a separate unittest for every bit worth testing.

Comment: I understood you don't want one test, but still: what your question sounded to me is more like [integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) than [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)... Integration testing is when you test interoperability of larger than "smallest testable unit" parts of the code.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I want to test the small bits that make up the application. e.g. if a public method inside of one of the classes works properly. Any ideas on how to rephrase the question to make that clear?

Comment: I think that this is a subject of Quality Assurance, sqa.stackexchange.com

Comment: how can we decide what you need to test? ideally: test everything.

Comment: @Nanne: Now I just need the definition of `everything` ;-) Every line of executable code? All non-generated code (e.g. excluding getters and setters)? Every functional line (e.g. excluding error handling)? Every public method? ...?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO:

1. Everything in the original specification.
2. Everything that is relied upon to work forever.
3. Everything that you found broken and had to fix.

Not terribly helpful I am sure - but realistic.

Unit tests should cover as much as you have time for and then cover everything you did not have time to test the last time you worked on them.

> What approach can be used to find chunks of work worth testing?

There are many:

- Whenever you find a bug, fix it and create a test that will ensure it never returns.

Comment: Point 3 is surely good to extend existing unittests. To get an initial set of unittests Point 1 sounds good. Thanks :-). (Point 2 is definitely good, but might be hard to work out)

Comment: @kdzia - Point 2 is intended to include stuff like shared library/utility classes.

Comment: okay, that's easier to identify ;-)